# converting object to string error

Tags: java, string, object, iterator

can somebody please tell me if this is the right way to convert an object to string? Firstly the error below

---

```
       public String generateResponse(HashSet<String> words){
            Iterator it = words.iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()){
                   String word = it.next(); // Object to string error
                   String input = responseMap.get(word);
                     if(input != null){
                       return input;
                     }
                }
       return pickDefaultResponse();
       }
```

---

Then i did this, and it worked.

```
       public String generateResponse(HashSet<String> words){
            Iterator it = words.iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()){   
                   String input = responseMap.get(it.next());// i put it here 
                     if(input != null){
                       return input;
                     }
                }
       return pickDefaultResponse();
       }
```

---

I was so curious about the error. I made a little research, since i'm just learning i don't know if this is right or wrong. it worked, but is it right?

```
        public String generateResponse(HashSet<String> words){
             Iterator it = words.iterator();
                 while(it.hasNext()){
                    String word = it.next().toString();// added toString()
                    String input = responseMap.get(word);
                      if(input != null){
                        return input;
                      }
                 }
       return pickDefaultResponse();
       }
```

Comment: use Iterator<String>.. and also it depends on what object you are adding to HashSet

Comment: Or just a for-each loop...

Comment: thanks. there is a String iterator.I learned something today :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Iterator it = words.iterator();
```

This statement ignores the type parameter of the iterator. That means the return type of `it.next()` is `Object`, which can't be assigned to `String` without a cast.

```
responseMap.get(it.next());
```

works, because the parameter of [`Map.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) has the type `Object`.

```
String word = it.next().toString();
```

Will work too, since the `Object` returned by `it.next()` actually is a `String` and therefore `toString` returns the same `String`.

This would work too:

```
String word = (String) (it.next());
```

But I recommend adding a type parameter to the `Iterator` variable:

```
Iterator<String> it = words.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    String word = it.next();
    // ...
```

**Note:** "Ignoring" a type parameter is a bad idea most times.

Comment: This explanation is helpful for a beginner like me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

String word = it.next()

firstly it does not have a " ; " to end the string, and secondly you need to explicitly cast it to String

change the code to String word = (String)it.next();

Answer (score 0):

change raw type iterator to generic type.

```
Iterator it = words.iterator();
```

to

```
Iterator<String> it = words.iterator();
```

Comment: @RyanG : if you find answer useful, you can upvote it that might help others. thanks

Comment: I've got only 8 rep points right now :( I'm prohibited to give an up vote, but i sincerely appreciate your help. thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

Yup it is

1. You cant assign a hashset directly to a string.

You have to convert it. using the toString method

2. As much to my info, in ur second case...
   when you use the below code

   "String input = responseMap.get(it.next());"

There are many overloaded methods for different datatypes. So when u provided a hashset directly. It worked correctly